# Match strings between two data frame and add missing strings to strings which are not complete in R

Tags: r, match

I have two data frames, with 4 different columns in different orders. One data frame `1` has an `ID` column with strings having the complete and correct name. Then I have a data frame `2` with a ID column which is not complete (`ID_not_complete`). Data frame `1` has more rows and contains 100% all strings from data frame `2`. I would like to add the missing strings to the `ID_not_complete` column in data frame `2`. As it is in my example, a string in data frame `2` can have multiple matches in data frame `1`, but only one matches the exact length of the string:

1. `rs1725 --> AX-42144793569__rs1725`
2. `rs1725 --> AX-42179369__rs1725074`

The first option should be the correct one.

Data frame 1

```
ID<-c("AX-35388475__rs16896864","AX-11425569__rs289621","AX-11102771__rs10261724","AX-42179369__rs1725074","AX-42144793569__rs1725","AX-42749369__rs264930","AX-32893019__rs6114382")
ID<-as.data.frame(ID)
```

Data frame 2

```
ID_not_complete<-c("rs16896864","rs289621","rs10261724","rs1725074","rs1725")
ID_not_complete <-as.data.frame(ID_not_complete)
```

The output data frame 2 should look like:

```
ID_complete<-c("AX-35388475__rs16896864","AX-11425569__rs289621","AX-11102771__rs10261724","AX-42179369__rs1725074","AX-42144793569__rs1725")
ID_complete <-as.data.frame(ID_complete)
```

I think I need to use `grep`. But I really don't know how to to it for each value in a column.

Comment: In vector ID element 6 is empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fuzzyjoin` package allows for joining on regular expressions (patterns).

A first (flawed) approach is:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(ID, ID_not_complete, by = c(ID="ID_not_complete"))
#                            ID ID_not_complete
# 1     AX-35388475__rs16896864      rs16896864
# 2       AX-11425569__rs289621        rs289621
# 3 AX-11102771__rs10261724          rs10261724
# 4      AX-42179369__rs1725074       rs1725074
# 5      AX-42179369__rs1725074          rs1725
# 6      AX-42144793569__rs1725          rs1725
```

where `rs1725` matches *both* `rs1725` and `rs1725074` (matching leading characters). I'll infer that you don't mean for this to happen, so a quick fix using some additional boundary-like patterns (also correcting for your data having spaces):

```r
ID_not_complete$ptn <- paste0("(^|[\\s_])", ID_not_complete$ID_not_complete, "([\\s_]|$)")
fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(ID, ID_not_complete, by = c(ID="ptn"))
#                            ID ID_not_complete                            ptn
# 1     AX-35388475__rs16896864      rs16896864 (^|[\\s_])rs16896864([\\s_]|$)
# 2       AX-11425569__rs289621        rs289621   (^|[\\s_])rs289621([\\s_]|$)
# 3 AX-11102771__rs10261724          rs10261724 (^|[\\s_])rs10261724([\\s_]|$)
# 4      AX-42179369__rs1725074       rs1725074  (^|[\\s_])rs1725074([\\s_]|$)
# 5      AX-42144793569__rs1725          rs1725     (^|[\\s_])rs1725([\\s_]|$)
```

(Side note: I originally wanted and intended to use the regex word-boundary `\b` in the pattern, but according to https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html, it considered `[A-Za-z0-9_]` to be "word characters", so the `_` preceding the real IDs was not a boundary. So if other users have a similar problem that does not use underscores, then the `(^|[\\s_])` can be replaced completely with `\\b`, similarly for the end-pattern.)

---

**Edit**

If all you need is to filter out from `ID` those that are not found otherwise, then perhaps just

```r
paste0("_(", paste(ID_not_complete$ID_not_complete, collapse = "|"), ") *$")
# [1] "_(rs16896864|rs289621|rs10261724|rs1725074|rs1725) *$"
grepl(paste0("_(", paste(ID_not_complete$ID_not_complete, collapse = "|"), ") *$"), ID$ID)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
ID[grepl(paste0("_(", paste(ID_not_complete$ID_not_complete, collapse = "|"), ") *$"), ID$ID),,drop=FALSE]
#                            ID
# 1     AX-35388475__rs16896864
# 2       AX-11425569__rs289621
# 3 AX-11102771__rs10261724    
# 4      AX-42179369__rs1725074
# 5      AX-42144793569__rs1725
```

or

```r
gsub("\\s", "", gsub(".*_", "", ID$ID))
# [1] "rs16896864" "rs289621"   "rs10261724" "rs1725074"  "rs1725"     "rs264930"   "rs6114382" 
ID[ gsub("\\s", "", gsub(".*_", "", ID$ID)) %in% ID_not_complete$ID_not_complete,,drop=FALSE]
#                            ID
# 1     AX-35388475__rs16896864
# 2       AX-11425569__rs289621
# 3 AX-11102771__rs10261724    
# 4      AX-42179369__rs1725074
# 5      AX-42144793569__rs1725
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice option. 
```df2$ptn <- paste0("(^|[\\s_])", df2$ID_not_complete, "([\\s_]|$)")
fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(df1$ID, df2$ID, by = c(ID="ptn"))```
When I want to perform this, then I get this error:
```Error in UseMethod("groups") : 
  no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character"```

Comment: `regex_inner_join`, along with every `*_join` and `merge` function, operates by joining two `data.frame`s, not columns or vectors; use `regex_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c(ID="ptn"))`. Don't try it on vectors.

Comment: ok thanks, when only comparing the two data frames with only the two columns in it, then my R crashes. the one data frame hast 333333 rows and the other one has 1000 rows. So unfortunately it doesn't work for me, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok thanks, the new edited commands helped and worked. Do you know maybe how I then get the output in the same order as the complete data frame 2? So I can then add the column back to its origin?

Comment: What makes you think that it is out of order? In the last two code blocks `ID` fields that match are in their original order.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Data:

```
ID <- c("AX-35388475__rs16896864","AX-11425569__rs289621","AX-11102771__rs10261724","AX-42179369__rs1725074","AX-42144793569__rs1725","AX-42749369__rs264930","AX-32893019__rs6114382")

df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = ID
)

ID_not_complete<-c("rs16896864","rs289621","rs10261724","rs1725074","rs1725")

df2 <- data.frame(
  ID_not_complete = ID_not_complete
)
```

Solution:
First define patterns:

```
patt0 <- paste0(sub("([^_]+)__(.*)", "\\2", df1$ID), collapse = "|")
patt1 <- paste0(df2$ID_not_complete, collapse = "|")
```

Now transform `df2$ID_not_complete`:

```
df2$ID_not_complete <- paste0(sub("([^_]+)__(.*)", "\\1__", df1$ID[grepl(patt1, df1$ID)]),
                          grep(patt0, df2$ID_not_complete, value = T))
```

Result:

```
df2
          ID_not_complete
1 AX-35388475__rs16896864
2   AX-11425569__rs289621
3 AX-11102771__rs10261724
4  AX-42179369__rs1725074
5  AX-42144793569__rs1725
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I want as output only the data frame 2. Do you know how to do this?